# CSS for ribbon end

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-shapes

How do I draw the end of a ribbon like the left side of this image using only CSS?
[image]

I know I can use the fact that corners in CSS are mitered, so I can have a `div` with a border of size 0 and other borders bigger to give me triangles. Is there a way to do this with only 1 `div`? Or do I need to stack some triangles? I'd really prefer to have 1 `div` so that users don't have to think about this and I can just use the CSS `:before` pseudo element to insert this. What's the best way to implement this?

IE9+ and modern versions of other browsers only need to be supported.

Comment: @at. Did you get any help with the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots off resources on the web showing how to do this. A very good tutorial is online at css-tricks here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

Ive also stuck it in a jsfiddle for you here to play with http://jsfiddle.net/WqNQU/

```
<h1 class="ribbon">
   <strong class="ribbon-content">Everybody loves ribbons</strong>
</h1>



.ribbon {
 font-size: 16px !important;
 /* This ribbon is based on a 16px font side and a 24px vertical rhythm. I've used em's to position each element for scalability. If you want to use a different font size you may have to play with the position of the ribbon elements */

 width: 50%;

 position: relative;
 background: #ba89b6;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 2em; /* Adjust to suit */
 margin: 2em auto 3em; /* Based on 24px vertical rhythm. 48px bottom margin - normally 24 but the ribbon 'graphics' take up 24px themselves so we double it. */
}
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: -1em;
 border: 1.5em solid #986794;
 z-index: -1;
}
.ribbon:before {
 left: -2em;
 border-right-width: 1.5em;
 border-left-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon:after {
 right: -2em;
 border-left-width: 1.5em;
 border-right-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #804f7c transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 left: 0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**HTML**

```
<div class="ribbon">
   <strong class="ribbon-content">Everybody loves ribbons</strong>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
    .ribbon {
     font-size: 16px !important;
     width: 50%;
     position: relative;
     background: #ba89b6;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 1em 2em; /* Adjust to suit */
     margin: 2em auto 3em; 
    }
    .ribbon:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     bottom: -1em;
     border: 1.5em solid #986794;
     z-index: -1;
    }
    .ribbon:before {
     left: -2em;
     border-right-width: 1.5em;
     border-left-color: transparent;
    }

.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #804f7c transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 left: 0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cszLX/)**

**[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/)**

Comment: I am impressed! Even IE8 supports this!

Comment: @BramVanroy Thank you mate ! Further tweaking is needed to match the image.

Comment: @freebird no need to further match the image, I was only interested in the end of the ribbon. Going to try this now.

Comment: This answer worked great. Actually all I needed was to make the left side transparent and it gave me that ribbon end! Very simple. However, this answer was the same exact one as @DominicGreen's and he answered first, so I have to award him the credit.